# PHP implode array to generate mysql IN criteria

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, zend-db

I have a function like the following:

```
public function foo ($cities = array('anaheim', 'baker', 'colfax') )
{
    $db = global instance of Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql...

    $query = 'SELECT name FROM user WHERE city IN ('.implode(',',$cities).')';
    $result = $db->fetchAll( $query );
}
```

This works out fine until someone passes $cities as an empty array.

To prevent this error I have been logic-breaking the query like so:

```
$query = 'SELECT name FROM user';
if (!empty($cities))
{
    $query .= ' WHERE city IN ('.implode(',',$cities).')';
}
```

but this isn't very elegant.  I feel like there should be a better way to filter by a list, but I am not sure how.  Any advice?

Comment: This will also break if a user submits a city that contains `'` (SQL injection) or a comma... You need to wrap them in `'` s

Comment: It is perfectly fine to do it this way. If there are no cities, you don't need a `WHERE` clause...

Comment: Looks fine to me, but you could use one of the many classes out there for making nice prepared queries.  At the very least, escape your strings!!  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: Apart from the concerns Pekka mentions, I see no reason why tagging on a `WHERE` clause depending on input would be inelegant. IMHO it's nicer then getting a meaningless `WHERE` clause that just means 'all'. However, even for variable-count IN's I still prefer prepared statements (usually using a `implode(',',array_fill(0,count($args),'?')`.

Comment: No, don't use mysql_real_escape_string. If $db is an instance of Zend_DB use *its* methods to either encode the query properly or to build a prepared, parametrized query. And concerning the where clause: Do you really _want_ your method foo() to do both, select some citites and select all cities? Personally I don't like that, those are two separate concerns -> two methods.

Comment: it is absolutely the same way i would've done it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least use the `quote` method...

```
if ($cities) {
    $query .= sprintf('WHERE city IN (%s)', implode(',', array_map(array($db, 'quote'), $cities)));
}
```

or, ideally, construct the query with Zend_Db_Select...

```
$select = $db->select()->from('user', 'name');

if ($cities) {
  foreach ($cities as $city) {
        $select->orWhere('city = ?', $city);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you do end up using the select object the `->where()` method will actually handle arrays for you.  Still need to check to see if there are items in the array, but this makes it a cleaner approach...

```
$select = $db->select()->from('user', 'name');

if ($cities) {
    $select->where('city IN (?)', $cities);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you know, from Zend Docs of Zend_Db_Adapter::quote
"If an array is passed as the value, the array values are quoted
     * and then returned as a comma-separated string."

So you could do this which is also quoted properly:

```
if ($cities) $query .= 'WHERE city IN ({$db->quote($cities}) ';
```

I love 1-liners :)