# MySql query in foreach statement PHP

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have this query in a PHP `foreach` statement:

```
<?php $i = 2; $j = 0; foreach($listings AS $listing): $i = $i == 2 ? 1 : 2;?>

...

<?php
    $db =& JFactory::getDBO();
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(product) FROM my_table WHERE contentid = 'I want content id here'";
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $count = $db->loadResult();

    echo ($count); //this print the count
?>

...

<?php endforeach;?>
```

How can I retrieve content id for each "listing" from MySQL database?

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(product) FROM my_table WHERE contentid = '**I want content id here**'";
```

I'm using joomla 2.5 and Jreviews. The listing id is "called" by `<?php echo $listing['Listing']['listing_id'];?>` into the `foreach` statement.

Comment: just to confirm, you are currently looping through your mysql result set and you want to perform another query for every iteration of that loop?

Comment: Sorry, comment was for @buymypies

Comment: I don't have time to remind myself to php and mysql but i wouldn't suggest performing another query for every iteration as that is simply overkill, build an array of the values you wish to query, and write a single query at the end to query everything use IN(), if i remember correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add the variable name to your query, assuming $i is the id:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(product) FROM my_table WHERE contentid = $i";
```

or better

```
$query = sprintf("SELECT COUNT(product) FROM my_table WHERE contentid = %d", $i);
```

Comment: Best way would be to use the WHERE ... IN () syntax without the foreach loop. Link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867840/php-implode-array-to-generate-mysql-in-criteria

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to prepare the needed data before outputting it.
In that particular case you can use only ONE SQL query with IN statement in the WHERE clause.